# Reduce spacing around buttons in UI

Tags: html, css, angular, vmware-clarity

I am using VMware clarity for UI and wants to reduce this spacing on left and right side of buttons i.e PDF button, ZIP button. I tried making padding as 0, and even negative padding but its not working. 
Below is the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;" (click)="pdf_report(hist)">
      <clr-icon class="is-solid" shape="file"></clr-icon>PDF     
</button>
```

Can someone tell me how can I do this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your elements are displayed according to flex behavior.
First you should take your dev tool to find where the styles about *button.btn.btn-sm* element are implemented. If you cannot change that, you can try to override it with important property by adding in the page/element/view your css code like this :

```css
  button.btn.btn-sm{
      display:inline-block!important;
      flex:none!important;// this will break the flex behavior
      padding:0!important;
      width:auto;
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" style="margin: 0%; padding: 0%;" (click)="pdf_report(hist)">
      <clr-icon class="is-solid" shape="file"></clr-icon>PDF     
</button>
```